# Determine List of Unsubscribers - EXM/List Manager

Tags: exm, list-manager

Sitecore 9.2

How can I determine which user has unsubscribed via a sent campaign?

Looking at xdb shards I see ListSubscriptions facet key and I see when a user is added and active.

Something like this: 
[image]

But I also see this: is this an unsubbed exm user?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no difference between someone who has never subscribed and and one who has unsubscribed.

You will need to add your own logic to the `HandleListUnsubscribe` or `UnsubscribeFromList` and possibly the `UnsubscribeFromAllEvent` pipelines.